# Function to convert hex to ascii in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm getting values in xquery but they are in HEX so I would like to know if there any function to convert a particular value from hex to ascii in xquery.

Comment: Simple answer: No. You have to write your own or use a library which offers this functionality.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ascii"? Ascii is a mapping between characters and integers, how do you convert hex to a mapping? I guess you mean you want to take a hex string, convert it into a sequence of integers, and return the character string whose ASCII codepoints correspond to those integers?

Comment: Yes Michael. I want a function to convert hex string and return ASCII form of it

Answer (score 1):

If your implementation supports the EXPath-binary library (see http://expath.org/spec/binary), then you can do

```
bin:decode-string(bin:hex($input))
```